# Elasticsearch not storing field, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have something like the following template in my Elasticsearch.  I just want certain part of the data returned, so I turn the source off, and explicitly stated store for the fields I want.

```
{
  "template_1" : {
    "order" : 20,
    "template" : "test*",
    "settings" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "_default_" : {
        "_source" : {
          "enabled" : false
        }
      },
      "type_1" : {
        "mydata" :
          "store" : "yes",
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I query the data, I don't get the fields back.  The query works, however, if I enable the _source field.  I am just starting with Elasticsearch, so I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field definitions should be wrapped in `properties` section of your mapping:

```
  "type_1" : {
    "properties": {
      "mydata" :
        "store" : "yes",
        "type" : "string"
      }
    }
  }
```